# Strange characters in my Oracle Database 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I used Oracle 11G database, i have a LOG table

when i write in this table with this function:

```
 Pk_Util.LOG_ERROR('Pk_Slt.IMPORT_LIAISON', 'LIAISON', NULL, liaison_code, NULL, SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200), SQLCODE);
```

I have this in my LOG table:

> 30/04/13,'Pk_Slt.IMPORT_LIAISON','LIAISON',null,**'
>   $¨%r?'**,null,'ORA-06502: PL/SQL','-6502','5484973'

My LOG_ERROR procedure:

```
 PROCEDURE LOG_ERROR(
  nom_procedure IN VARCHAR2,
  type_entite   IN VARCHAR2,
  id_entite     IN INTEGER,
  code_entite   IN VARCHAR2,
  date_entite   IN DATE,
  error_message IN VARCHAR2,
  sql_code      IN INTEGER
 ) IS
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO LOG(LOG_ID,LOG_DATE, LOG_PROCEDURE, LOG_TYPE_ENTITE, LOG_ID_ENTITE, LOG_CODE_ENTITE, LOG_DATE_ENTITE, LOG_SQLERRM, LOG_SQLCODE)
    VALUES (SEQ_LOG.NEXTVAL,SYSDATE, nom_procedure, type_entite, id_entite, code_entite, date_entite, error_message, sql_code);
 END;
```

PS:

I am passing liaison_code when calling the method this datatype:

LURE 3B.RE61 
THANN3AMARI2 
C.SAU3ZCRIM1 
PYMON6VOUGL1 
 ARGIE3ARSOT1
 NEUVY 3 
ZNEUV 3 1
....

Thanks

Comment: In other words your liaison_code is `$¨%r?`..?

Comment: is a varchar --> code_entite IN VARCHAR2

Comment: @Mercer What are you passing in as `liaison_code` when calling the method?

Comment: Those characters can be stored in a varchar2...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson this type: LURE 3B.RE61 THANN3AMARI2 C.SAU3ZCRIM1 PYMON6VOUGL1

Comment: We need the full string, and the special chars as well (for example it looks like there are hidden carriage returns in your extract)

Comment: @Sebas how to remove the carriage return when inserting my data

Comment: @Mercer it depends from where comes the liaison_code content, but the idea is to replace chr(13) and chr(10) by whatever you prefer (a space?)